# For a tablespace what does the value 3 mean in the online column?

Tags: oracle

I have a problematic tablespace that I cannot get rid of. When I try drop it, I get informed that it doesn't exist, but when I look into `TS$` it's definitely there. The only clue I have right now, is that it has the value 3 written in column `Online$`. I'm guessing that it means that it's hidden, but truth to be told, I cannot find concrete information about this column on the internet. What does this value mean? Can I change it back to **online**/**offline**, so I can drop it?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using, and what specifics on this tablespace do you have? What is visible in DBA_TABLESPACES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the tablespace was dropped:

```
SQL> create tablespace ts1 datafile '/tmp/ts1.dbf' size 10M;

Tablespace created.

SQL> select online$ from ts$ where name = 'TS1';

   ONLINE$
----------
         1

SQL> drop tablespace ts1 including contents and datafiles;

Tablespace dropped.

SQL> select online$ from ts$ where name = 'TS1';

   ONLINE$
----------
         3

SQL>
```

The definition of the view `DBA_TABLESPACES` even has a filter to exclude such tablespaces.

```
SQL> select substr(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', 'DBA_TABLESPACES'), -202) from dual;

SUBSTR(DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('VIEW','DBA_TABLESPACES'),-202)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
from sys.ts$ ts, sys.x$kcfistsa tsattr, sys.imsvcts$ svc
where ts.online$ != 3 
and bitand(flags,2048) != 2048
and bitand(ts.flags, 16777216) != 16777216
and ts.ts# = tsattr.tsid
and ts.ts# = svc.ts# (+)


SQL>
```

You can check the meaning of other values also in the definition of the above view:

```
SQL> with t as (select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', 'DBA_TABLESPACES') x from dual) select substr(t.x, instr(t.x, 'online$'), 100) from t;

SUBSTR(T.X,INSTR(T.X,'ONLINE$'),100)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
online$, 1, 'ONLINE', 2, 'OFFLINE',
                 4, 'READ ONLY', 'UNDEFINED'),
          decode(


SQL>
```